# Callback inside inlineCallbacks function

Tags: python, callback, twisted, yield

Let's say I have a function like this:

```
def display(this, that):
    print this, that
```

and a class:

```
class Runner(object):
    def __init__(self, callback):
        self.callback = callback
        self.loop = twisted.internet.task.LoopingCall(repeat)
        self.loop.start(0)

    @defer.inlineCallbacks
    def repeat(self):
        this = yield do_this()
        that = yield do_that()

        if this and that:
            # now I want to call the callback function
            yield self.callback(this, that) # makes sense?

runner = Runner(display)
reactor.run()
```

Basically what I want to do is I want to create a Runner class which will do some specific tasks and every time it gets a result, it will call the given callback function. Instead of creating a new function which does a specific thing, I want to create a generic class which does only one thing. E.g:

```
class TwitterReader(object):
    def __init__(self, callback):
        ...
        ...

    @defer.inlineCallbacks
    def get_messages(self):
        ...
        ...
        yield callback(messages)

class MessageFilter(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.bad_messages = open('bad_messages.txt', 'w')
        self.twitter = TwitterReader(self.message_received)

    def message_received(messages):
        for message in messages:
            for bad_word in BAD_WORDS:
                if bad_word in message:
                    self.bad_messages.write(message)
                    break
```

I'm new to twisted. So, I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it. Is it?

Thanks

Comment: @Johnsyweb Okay, I've added some comments

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `callback` inside `repeat` should instead be `self.callback`.

Other than that your example should work exactly as written.

Comment: Okay, I fixed it, thanks. But my question is about the design. Not sure if it's right or wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You'd only *need* to `yield self.callback` if it returned a deferred and you wanted to wait for the result before exiting the `repeat` function. In your example, your callback is a normal function (which effectively returns `None`), so there is no advantage to yielding - however it is allowed to yield non-deferred values so no harm is done. From the [inlineCallbacks docs](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/16.1.0/api/twisted.internet.defer.html#inlineCallbacks):

> Things that are not Deferreds may also be yielded, and your generator
>   will be resumed with the same object sent back. This means yield
>   performs an operation roughly equivalent to maybeDeferred.

If your callback *did* return a deferred (eg, if it was also an `inlineCallbacks` decorated function) then yielding would pause execution of `repeat` until the deferred completed. This may or may not be desirable in your application.